# npm error messages when installing packages as sudo user

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I am trying to install express via npm in node (nodejs). I am the user 'kev' and this user is sudo. I cannot use a sudo command to install anything as it cannot find npm at all when I 'sudo npm' for some bizarre reason. I have tried adding symbolic links but sudo'ing still refuses to find npm. So running as a standard user and trying to install express using npm I get the following errors:

```
kev@tentimes:~$ npm install express

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/kev/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/kev/package.json'
npm WARN kev No description
npm WARN kev No repository field.
npm WARN kev No README data
npm WARN kev No license field.
```

I have no idea what the errors mean, except that it seems to me it may be due to me not elevating to sudo to install using nvm. Anyone have any suggestions? It is my first time installing express with node/nvm and I am following some recent guides on how to do this, but the guides just say to use "nvm install express" and this is just supposed to work. As a by the way, I have git setup, but is that why it is complaining about repositories?

Comment: There is no `package.json`, thats what npm is complaining about. But thats just a warning, it should install express anyway.

Comment: err, so I have to install json first with something? I just assumed something so basic as json is already included with ubuntu?

Comment: Aha! 'npm install json' before 'npm install express' fixes everything! Please put as an answer if you want and I will give you the credit. Extra imaginary bonus points if you want to add any interesting details as to what is going on here - thanks ;)

Comment: You don't need to install json. You need to [initialize your package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM is a package manager, and as it's name implies, it works with packages. A package is, basically, a folder or repository with a `package.json` file in it, which contains all kinds of metadata about the package. This file is missing as the error tells you:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/kev/package.json'
```

Thats fine, it should install the package anyway, check the `./node_modules` folder. However it's recommended that you yourself initialize a nodejs package with `npm init` which will ask you a few questions about the package you're going to write. Afterwards, `npm install --save express` installs `express` *and saves the dependency in your own `package.json` file* so the next time you can just `npm install` and npm will happily install all dependencies listed in your own `package.json` file.

Here is some more documentation about what the package.json is and what information it contains: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json